# syntax error: unexpected son, expecting semicolon, newline, or }

Tags: go

I got this error when I used normal keyboard for `'` in json format as below.

```
type Movie struct {
Title   string
Year    int     'json:"released"'
Color   bool    'json:"color,omitempty"'
Actors  []string}

`-go run * ----> :syntax error: unexpected son, expecting semicolon, newline, or }
```

and, then, I copied " ` " from stackOverflow and replaced with the original ones as below

```
type Movie struct {
Title   string
Year    int     `json:"released"`
Color   bool    `json:"color,omitempty"`
Actors  []string}
```

and, then, the syntax is gone :(
does GO file expect ' as unicode or is there any setting for that?

Comment: backtick located above of your tab key on your keyboard

Comment: Not above every keyboard, but I got the point. This question and the answer helped me a lot! Thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

These two are distinct characters: the apostrophe (') and backtick (`). The Go language uses backticks for struct type annotations, also called struct tags. In your example, they were used to annotate JSON key names for the `encoding/json` package to use. See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/254076/how-do-i-type-the-tick-and-backtick-characters-on-windows#254077) on how to input them.

Comment: Oh, GoLang uses backtick. Thank you ma_il.